# How to copy glyphs between two strikes in fontforge without scaling?

Tags: fontforge

I am using fontforge to try to convert a 6x13 bitmap font to 6x12, but without scaling, only removing the top pixel row.

I created another strike, but whe I copy from 6x13 to 6x12, then it automatically scale it... How to copy as is ? (rasterizing is not a solution since it tries to scale, while I want the glyph exactly identical)